# Solucionar error 500 en proyecto Angular con Express

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, express

Mi api en express hace bien la consulta de mostrarme todo desde mi base de datos.

En Angular tengo un modal donde se tienen que ingresar registros, guardarlos y mostrarlos en la lista que se observa:

Esta es la lista
[image: Esta es la lista]

Estos son los errores que me da en consola del navegador al presionar el boton de "Guardar Cambios"
[image: Estos son los errores que me da en consola del navegador]

A continuacion les pondre el codigo de la aplicacion:

```
    export class DataService {
  private updateZombies$ = new Subject<any>();
  zombiesObservable = this.updateZombies$.asObservable();

  constructor(private _client: HttpClient) { }

  async obtenerZombies(){
    let zombies = await this._client.get<any>(apiUrl + 'zombies');
    return this.updateZombies$.next(zombies);
  }
  obtenerCerebros(){
    return this._client.get(apiUrl + 'cerebros');
  }

  agregarZombie(nombre: string, email: string, tipo: string){
    let nuevoZombie ={
      nombre: nombre,
      email: email,
      type: tipo
    };

    return this._client.post(apiUrl + "zombies/new-zombie", nuevoZombie);

  }
  eliminarZombie(id){
    return this._client.delete(`${apiUrl}zombies/delete/${id}`);
  }

}
```

en este bloque es el modal:

```
    export class ZombiesModalsComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('modal',{static: true}) public modal: ElementRef;

  nombre: string;
  email: string;
  tipo: string;
  error: string;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService, private _renderer: Renderer2) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  agregarZombie(){
    debugger;
    this.dataService.agregarZombie(
      this.nombre,
       this.email, 
       this.tipo
       ).subscribe((resultado) =>{
        this._renderer.selectRootElement(this.modal.nativeElement, true).click();
      this.dataService.obtenerZombies();
    },(error)=>{
      console.log(error);
    })
  }

}
```

Mi api:

```
  export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiUrl: 'http://localhost:4000/api/'
};
```

el boton donde mandamos a llamar al metodo:

```
 <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="agregarZombie()">Guardar Cambios</button>
            </div>
```

Express:

```
    let express = require('express');
let router = express.Router();

let Zombie = require('../models/Zombie');
let Cerebro = require('../models/Cerebro');

router.get('/zombies', async(req, res)=>{
    Zombie.find().exec((error,zombies)=>{
        if(!error){
            res.status(200).json(zombies);
        }else{
            res.status(500).json(error);
        }
    });
})

router.post('/zombies/new-zombie', function(req, res){
    let data = req.body;

    var nuevoZombie = new Zombie({
        nombre: data.nombre,
        email: data.email,
        type: data.type
    });

    nuevoZombie.save(function(error){
        if(error){
            let mensaje = error.messaje;
            res.status(500).json({mensajeError: mensaje, mensajeExito:''})
        }else{
            res.status(200).json({mensajeError:'', mensajeExito: 'Se agrego correctamente'})
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Trata de colocar tu codigo y no imagenes.

Comment: Perdón no sabia como ponerlo pero ya esta

Comment: Si usas Mongoose, a la función `callback`, que estás pasando al método `save` de tu modelo, le hace falta un argumento: `function(error, saved){ ... }`. Por otro lado el mensaje de error no muestra nada ya que usas: *error.messaje* y dicho atributo no existe, debes colocar: *error.message*. De todas formas en Express es buena práctica usar `console.error(error);` cuando estás depurando errores. Por último, estamos en 2020, no uses `var` en JS del lado Servidor, usa `let` y `const`, según sea necesario. Saludos